# Calculate the Directional Derivative of $f (x, y, z) = x z + \sin (x z + y)$ at $[−4,−2,−2]$ in the direction of the vector $[3, −3, −2]$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to calculate the directional derivative of the function

$$f (x, y, z) = x z + \sin (x z + y)$$

at the point $[−4, −2, −2]$ in the direction given by the vector $[3, −3, −2]$.

I have done several calculations but the answer seems to be wrong. Can anyone spot where I have done some error or if I have missed any step in the solution? Here are my calculations:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have a simple error in the last line: $$-6\cos(6) - 3\cos(6) + 8\cos(6) = -\cos(6)$$ instead of  $$-3\cos(6).$$